# Referencing a Worksheet: Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I managed to get my code working except this part:

```vb
' colle data / année
Windows(Namepatch3).Activate
For j = 0 To (finas - debutas)
    Worksheets(1).Cells(2 + cpt, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
    'MsgBox (Vcol(j))
Next j
           
cpt = cpt + 1
```

Returning into an

> "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

All variables are declared and Namepatch3 is declared As ThisWorkbook.

EDIT: Here the full code of this part:

```vb
Sub Chiffres()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim Filt As String
    Dim IndexFiltre As Integer
    Dim NomFichier As Variant
    Dim Titre As String
    Dim o As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim Msg1 As String
    Dim ConsoPDC As Workbook
    Dim Fichier As String
    Dim chaine As String
    Dim feuille As Variant
    Dim Reponse As Integer
    Dim Config As Integer
    Dim nomClasseur As Variant
    Dim vclasseur As Workbook
    Dim resum As Workbook
    
    [B65000].End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1).Select
       
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    '   Définit la liste des filtres de fichiers
    Filt = "Fichiers texte (*.txt),*.txt," & _
      "Fichiers Lotus (*.prn),*.prn," & _
      "Fichiers séparés par des virgules (*.csv),*.csv," & _
      "Fichiers ASCII (*.asc),*.asc," & _
      "Tous les fichiers (*.*),*.*"
    
    '   Affiche *.* par défaut
    IndexFiltre = 5
    
    '   Définit la légende de la boîte de dialogue
    Titre = "Sélectionner les fichiers à traiter"
    
    '   Obtenir le nom de fichier
    NomFichier = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (fileFilter:=Filt, _
      FilterIndex:=IndexFiltre, _
      Title:=Titre, _
      MultiSelect:=True)
    
    '   Quitter si la boîte de dialogue est annulée
    If Not IsArray(NomFichier) Then
        MsgBox "Aucun fichier n'a été sélectionné!"
        GoTo TheEnd
    End If
    
    '   Affiche le chemin complet et le nom des fichiers
    Config = vbYesNo + vbInformation + vbDefaultButton2
    For o = LBound(NomFichier) To UBound(NomFichier)
         Msg = Msg & NomFichier(o)
    Next o
    Reponse = MsgBox("Ci-dessous vos fichiers selectionnés :" & vbCrLf & Msg & vbCrLf, Config, _
      "MAJ resum")
    If Reponse = vbNo Then GoTo TheEnd
    
    For p = LBound(NomFichier) To UBound(NomFichier)
        Msg1 = NomFichier(p)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Msg1
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'Declare le classeur actif
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Affiche la barre de statut en bas à gauche de l'écran (si elle ne l'est pas déjà)
    Application.StatusBar = "MAJ resum - Traitement fichier " & _
      ActiveWorkbook.Name & " - merci de patienter SVP ..."
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Ne selectionne que le nom du fichier à l'intérieur du chemin
    fichier1 = Right(Msg1, Len(Msg1) - InStrRev(Msg1, "\", -1, 1))
    Fichier = Left(fichier1, InStr(fichier1, ".xls") - 1)
    
    'traitement import
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' ***************
    ' *      Macro1
    ' ***************
    
    ' appel raz dest
    'Call M_raz_dest
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim l  As Integer
    
    Dim debutcols As Integer ' année en nombre ?
    Dim fincols As Integer ' année en nombre ?
    Dim debutas As Integer ' n° col année debut
    Dim finas As Integer ' n° col année fin
    Dim debutcold As Integer
    Dim fincold As Integer
    Dim debutad As Integer
    Dim finad As Integer
    Dim rowmaxwallets As Integer
    Dim rowmaxwalletd As Integer
    Dim c As Object
    Dim therow As Integer
    Dim Nlp As String
    Dim Vcol(30) As Long ' data col année
    Dim com(30) As String  ' data col commentaires
    Dim cpt As Integer
    
    Windows(fichier1).Activate
    Sheets("DataBase").Select
    
    ' lire Année début dans col V / 22 onglet source et n° de colonne
    debutcols = CInt(Worksheets("DataBase").Cells(1, 22))  ' (col V)  XXXX
    debutas = 22
    fincols = 0
    fincold = 0
    finas = 0
    debutad = 0
    finad = 0
    
    ' lecture colonne de fin dans Onglet Source
    i = 0
    For i = 1 To 30
        If Len(Worksheets("DataBase").Cells(1, i + 22)) = 4 Then
            ' année 4 digits trouvée
        Else
            ' plus une colonne Année
        i = i - 1
        finas = (22 + i)
        fincols = CInt(Worksheets("DataBase").Cells(1, i + 22))
        GoTo sortie
    End If
    Next i
    
sortie:
    'MsgBox ("Lettre de colonne de début sur Source :" & ConvertCol(debutas))
    'MsgBox ("Lettre de colonne de fin sur Source :" & ConvertCol(finas))
    Columns(ConvertCol(debutas) & ":" & ConvertCol(finas)).Select
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Select
    i = 0
       
    For i = 1 To 70
        If Worksheets(1).Cells(2, i) = debutcols Then
            debutcold = i
            debutad = i
            'MsgBox ("N° de colonne de début sur Dest : " & debutad)
            GoTo sortie2
        End If
    Next i
       
sortie2:
    'MsgBox ("Lettre de colonne de début sur onglet Dest :" & ConvertCol(debutad))
    finad = debutad + (finas - debutas)
    'MsgBox ("Lettre de colonne de fin sur onglet Dest :" & ConvertCol(finad))
    Windows(fichier1).Activate
    Sheets("DataBase").Select
    rowmaxwallets = CInt(Worksheets("DataBase").Cells(Columns(1).Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    'MsgBox ("Nbr de lignes dans onglet Source à traiter : " & rowmaxwallets - 2)
    'rowmaxwalletd = CInt(Worksheets("LP").Cells(Columns(1).Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    'MsgBox ("Nbr de LP dans onglet LP à parcourir : " & rowmaxwalletd - 2)
    i = 0
    cpt = 1
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       
    'lecture fichier source
    For l = 1 To rowmaxwallets
        ' copie data année en dynamique / colonne
        
        Windows(fichier1).Activate
        For j = 0 To (finas - debutas)
            Vcol(j) = Worksheets("DataBase").Cells(1822 + l, debutas + j)
        Next j
           
        ' colle data / année
    
        For j = 0 To (finas - debutas)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(2 + cpt, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
            'MsgBox (Vcol(j))
        Next j
           
        cpt = cpt + 1
         
    Next l
fin:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
       
    Sheets("Dest").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    MsgBox ("Import terminé !")
    
TheEnd:
    
End Sub
```

I know there is still some `.Activate` but I need to make the code works before optimizing it.

Comment: Should I erase Worksheets(1) or define Namepatch3 again ?

Comment: Now it gives me the error:
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
Glad to see that we are moving forward :)

Just to be a bit more precise: I need to import datas from one workbook into another one. Those datas are in a range of column that always begin in V but It's size is variable (can go from V to W to V to AE approx.). And each column may see it's header changed (from 2010 to 2030 approx.)

Comment: Maybe include the line where you are defining Namepatch3.

Comment: Namepatch3 is defined as below:

    'Namepatch3 = ThisWorkbook.Name'

Comment: Same error: Object doesn't support this property or method" but on the `Namepatch3 = ThisWorkbook` line

Dim Namepatch3 is:
`Public Namepatch3 As String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Activate line as that is unnecessary. Instead, fully qualify your worksheet reference like this:

```
Dim Namepatch3 As WorkBook
Set Namepatch3 = ThisWorkbook
```

Then in your Loop:

```
Namepatch3.Worksheets(1).Cells(2 + cpt, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
```

Or just simplify it all like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2 + cpt, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
```

Comment: New error on another line a bit above:
`Namepatch3.Worksheets(1).Select`
System is telling me "Select method of worksheet class failed."

Thanks for your time and attention buddy, really really appreciated :)

Comment: I do not see the  need for `Namepatch3` in this context. You can just use `ThisWorkbook` instead. See the last line of my answer.

Comment: Ok, I just replaced my `Namepatch3` with `ThisWorkbook`.
A new error replaced the old one:
"Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Once again, glad to see that we are going forward on the issue :)

Comment: Did you also remove all references to `Namepatch3`? You may want to update your question with more complete code of what you currently have.

Comment: I removed all references to Namepatch3, i'll update my original question with my code :)